# Click on link using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am trying to automatically click a link when the page loads using jQuery. I have done it successfully in past projects, but I am not able to get it to work now. Here is my code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){
      $(".btn-warning").trigger("click");
    });
</script>

<!-- Modal -->
<a href="#myModal2" role="button" class="btn btn-warning" data-toggle="modal">Confirm</a>
<div id="myModal2" class="modal hide fade" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel2" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true"></button>
        <h3 id="myModalLabel2">Alert Header</h3>
    </div>
    <div class="modal-body">
        <p>Body goes here...</p>
    </div>
    <div class="modal-footer">
        <button data-dismiss="modal" class="btn green">OK</button>
    </div>
</div>
```

I believe the `data-toggle="modal"` part of the code is messing things up. But if I remove this, the modal does not work at all. Maybe I need to use something other than the `click` value?

Comment: Are you using bootsrap?

Comment: Why are you selecting the button using its class?

Comment: this will only work if the click action is defined by jquery too

Comment: @doitlikejustin Yes, I am using bootstrap.

Comment: Ok, answered the question below.

Comment: What browser did you use to test it?

Comment: @sza latest version of Chrome

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you said you are using Bootsrap. I would suggest the following (below) instead of using a click event.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    jQuery(window).load(function($){
        $('#myModal2').modal('show');
    });
</script>
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/RsdpT/1/

Another Fiddle (thanks to @FakeRainBrigand): http://jsfiddle.net/nHD9U/2/

Comment: Just tried this as well and it did not work unfortunately. Any other ideas?

Comment: Is the `id` of your modal `"#myModal2`

Comment: No, there is no id.  Just 2 classes

Comment: You need to add the `id` to the actual modal you are trying to "popup". Also I updated my code

Comment: @three3 Just so you can see what I am referring to when referring to the modal `id`... Under the `<!-- Modal -->` in this screenshot http://d.pr/i/tZpZ and the link... http://getbootstrap.com/2.3.2/javascript.html#modals

Comment: Just used your updated code and it still did not work. I am going to post my full code to my original post. Maybe this will help

Comment: Thanks for the detailed code. For some reason (I copied the code from fiddle) and it still will not work for me. I cannot get it!

Comment: Can you share a link?

Comment: Unfortunately, I cannot. I can share a detailed screenshot of my code though. Will post in a sec.

Comment: @three3 Is the code even being `echo`ed? Also... does the modal even work when you click on the button? Maybe you can send a screenshot of the echoed source code...

Comment: Yes, the code is echoed and it does work when I click the button

Comment: @three3 how about screenshot of echoed code? Can you check your Chrome Console as well to see if there are errors. If no luck with that then I am not sure since I can see it's working the the Fiddle.

Comment: Here is the echoed code: imgur.com/EVosxI4. Here are the errors in the console: http://imgur.com/UPg7UOY

Answer (score 0):

You could try:

```
$(".btn-warning").click();
```

Comment: `.click()` is just a shortcut to `.trigger("click")`.

Comment: This answer definitely **deserves** a down-vote, but I don't like to down-vote (even in "revenge"). At least here, you showed some code and seemingly tried to help the OP. (have you noticed that not a single down-vote from me still affects your rep? -- they were all deleted)

Answer (score 0):

How about

```
$(".btn-warning")[0].click();
```

Comment: @Jasper They do actually have their own [`.click()` method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement.click), as well. Not sure how well it works with jQuery bindings.

Comment: @three3 It got to be something else in your code. Try to delete all js references and then add it back one by one and test.

Answer (score 0):

Why not just do what you want directly:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    location.hash = "myModal2";
});
```